# (Why) are there no FIDO keys with displays?

Tags: fido-u2f, fido

Since FIDO keys have no displays, you can only use them to authenticate yourself, not to authorize some action (you don't know what action you'd be authorizing).

Or, if you want to authorize something, you need to trust your browser that it is displaying the same thing as it will authorize as soon as you press the button on the FIDO key - but then I wonder why you need a hardware key at all, and don't just fully trust your browser with your keys.

So I somehow fail to see the usefulness of FIDO keys. Can someone enlighten me, please?

Even for some simple example, as logging in to my email account - shouldn't that be something better than just authentication? As soon as I've logged in, an attacker that controls my browser (browser is man-in-the-middle) can stay logged in forever, add a forwarding rule to intercept all my emails, and so on.

All this because the FIDO keys would become inconveniently large if they had to include a display? Then why not just add a headphone jack, and at least tell me via text-to-speech what I'm authorizing?

Comment: The FIDO specification (or one of the related ones) includes *Secure Display*. It's optional and I have yet to come across one implementing it. Dedicated FIDO keys will likely remain rare. But I'm hoping that the full FIDO standard will be implemented by Windows, macOS, Android and iOS. At least Android and iOS devices have isolated security hardware that already implements the equivalent of *Secure Display*. Windows and macOS also implement something very similar. It's just not available by a standardized API let alone the FIDO / WebAuthn API.

Comment: @Codo, do you expect the phone or Windows PC to be a FIDO key itself, so that no extra hardware key is needed? Or that the phone or Windows PC provides a Secure display to the FIDO device, authenticating itself as beeing from a vendor that's trusted by the FIDO device?

Comment: The phones and computers already are FIDO keys. I think Windows 10 and later Android support it both in the browser and via a native API while iOS and macOS are restricted to the browser. But it might have changed. They all might have prerequisites like Touch ID capable device on macOS and Windows Hello capable device for Windows.